# Dealing with array of type struct

Tags: c++, arrays, struct

I have problem in: Re-Using array of struct

The 1D array (Trans) is global:

```
struct Transaction
{
    int Item;
    float prob;
    int support;
    Transaction *next;
};

#define ItemNum 1000
Transaction *Trans[ItemNum]; 
Transaction *PairItems[ItemNum][ItemNum];
```

I initialize Trans as:

```
for (int a = 0; a <= ItemNum - 1; a++)
        Trans[a] = NULL;
```

Then I fill this array with input from text file. In specific:

```
i = 0;
    while (!inFile.eof())
    {
        FollowingItem = NULL;
        getline(inFile, line);
        std::stringstream in(line);

        while (in >> a >> b)
        {
                NewItem = new Transaction;
                NewItem->Item= a;
                NewItem->prob = b;
                NewItem->next = NULL;

                if (Trans[i] == NULL)
                    Trans[i] = FollowingItem = NewItem;
                else
                {
                    FollowingItem->next = NewItem;
                    FollowingItem = NewItem;
                }
        }
        i++;
   }
```

Then, I print it:

```
i=0;
while (Trans[i] != NULL)
        {
            while (Trans[i] != NULL)
            {
                cout << Trans[i]->Item << " " << Trans[i]->prob<<" ";
                Trans[i] = Trans[i]->next;
            }
            cout << "\n";
            i++;
        }
```

Until Now, everything is okay,

**BUT**

When I try to use **Trans** again, I can't, since the array become empty!!

for example, if I do this code:

```
for (int a = 0; a <= ItemNum - 1; a++)
    for (int b = 0; b <= ItemNum - 1; b++)
    {
        PairItems[a][b] = new Transaction;
        PairItems[a][b]->support = 0;
    }

            int k = 0;
        while (Trans[k] != NULL)
        {
            int l = 0;
            while (Trans[l] != NULL)
            {
                PairItems[k][l]->Item = Trans[k]->Item;
                PairItems[k][l]->prob = Trans[k]->prob;
                PairItems[k][l]->support += 1;
                cout << PairItems[k][l]->Item << " " ;
                Trans[k] = Trans[k]->next;
                l++;
            }
            cout << "\n";
            k++;
        }
```

the compiler ignores this condition:

> while (Trans[k] != NULL)

because **Trans[k]=NULL**. I don't know way!

But when I delete the printing code, **Trans[k] !=  NULL** and the compiler enter to the condition and execute the rest!!

I think the problem associated with the initializing the arrays of structure, but I couldn't find the solution

Please Help

Thanks

Comment: Your `i++` is outside the while loop!(2nd bit of code)

Comment: **i** refer to the current row/line in text file. I want to fill the array of structure **Trans** such that:   **Trans[0]=** set of items from file (extract and store all elements in first line of file) as linked list, and  **Trans[1]=** set of items from file (extract and store all elements in second line of file) as linked list, and so on.

Comment: Somewhat related: Confirm those arrays aren't sitting in `main()`, particularly the second one, which *minimum* on a 32bit implementation will be just-shy of 4MB. If local to `main()` and this *works*, you have a considerably beefier stack than I certainly do. Also, there are considerably easier ways to populate a linked table than that.

Comment: *"Until now everything is ok*" No: don't use `!eof()` to check for end of data. Also you use a lot of (raw) pointers here.

Comment: Thank you, but what should I use to check for end of data(file)??. I faced a hard time to chose the good data structure to store data file, where each line in the file has to be on array, so I used array of linked list! what are you suggesting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your print code modify the array, in particular `Trans[i] = Trans[i]->next;`

Your print function may be written:

```
for (int i = 0; Trans[i] != NULL; ++i) {
    for (const Transaction* it = Trans[i]; it != NULL; it = it->next) {
        std::cout << it->Item << " " << it->prob <<" ";
    }
    cout << "\n";
}
```

BTW, you may use `std::vector<std::list<Transaction> > Trans` instead of hard-coded array of handwritten list.

Comment: Thank you so much, I didn't notice that I re-witting in my array!. I'm not expert in the new way of programing (using vector and list) but tanks for introducing them. i believe i have to learn them since i will deal with large file .